How can I convert theme colors in SpreadJs (Accent 1, Accent 2 etc) to the actual color
If the user applied colors from a theme, internally are named and stored as Accent 1; Accent 2, etc.
Internally, in the JSON data, they also have the opacity: Accent 1 -0; Accent 2 -50, etc.
¿Is there a way to convert those "magic names" to rgb, hexa or something?
UPDATE:
I use the SpreadJS integration for 4D.  I can extract the cell content with styles like font, size, style and explicit colors for each span in a cell.
To find what "Accent 1" means I need to check the theme.themeColor property for the sheet, but there are no direct matches.
…theme.themeColor.accent1 is the property in the theme properties. The value, in this case, is {a:255,r:91,g:155,b:213}.
But…
…richText[3].style.foreColor, (the property I found in the cell content) has the value "Accent 1 80".
So I need a big conditional to match literal strings like "Accent 1" with properties named  like ".accent1". And then evaluate the opacity value: 0, 50, -50, 80, -80… For each and every span with colors.
That's why I have asked for a way to transform magic literals to explicit colors.

why do you need to get those colors.  they depend on the excel file theme colors and are not static values.
